# How to replace kernel module in FreeBSD?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I am trying to get an LSI 9300 SAS HBA working in FreeBSD 11.2.  I'm currently running driver 18:

```
# dmesg | grep mpr
mpr0: <Avago Technologies (LSI) SAS3008> port 0xa000-0xa0ff mem 0xfb300000-0xfb30ffff at device 0.0 numa-domain 0 on pci5
mpr0: Firmware: 05.00.00.00, Driver: 18.03.00.00-fbsd
```

I'm having trouble seeing all the disks so I want to update the driver to version 20 but I don't know how to update it.  I downloaded it and tried:

```
# kldload ./mpr.ko
kldload: can't load ./mpr.ko: module already loaded or in kernel.
```

Since this module does not appear in `kldstat` unless I use `-v`, I believe this means it's built into the kernel.  On Linux I could blacklist it in `modprobe.d` but how does this work on FreeBSD?

Comment: Get FreeSD sources and take a look into `sys/amd64/conf/GENERIC` file.

Comment: Are you saying I have to recompile the kernel just to update a driver?

Comment: AFAIK, it is an only way, if the driver is statically compiled into the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from LSI support is actually very simple.

Copy the file **mpr.ko** to `/boot/kernel/` and add this line to `/boot/loader.conf`:

```
mpr_load="YES"
```